# How to save id no. as a image name in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am a begineer in yii. I am making a basic structure - an employee. I am uploading their images and saving image name in database and also showing it on my view page. But I want to change the image name to employee id.

For Ex:

`desert.jpg` changes to `01.jpg` or any other employee id.

Please help me.

CONTROLLER:

```
public function actioncreate(){
    $dept_list    =    department_mod::model()->dept_list();
    $data['dept_list']    =    CHtml::listData($dept_list,'value', 'text');

    $team_list    =    team_mod::model()->team_list();
    $data['team_list']    =    CHtml::listData($team_list,'value', 'text');

    $des_list    =    employee_mod::model()->des_list();
    $data['des_list']    =    CHtml::listData($des_list,'value', 'text');

    $report_to_list    =    report_to_mod::model()->report_to_list();
    $data['report_to_list']    =    CHtml::listData($report_to_list,'value', 'text');

    $model_upload = new upload_mod;
    $data['model_upload'] = $model_upload;        

    $this->render('create',$data);
}


public function actionsave(){
    $q = Employee_mod::model()->data_save($_POST);

    $data = $_POST;
    $exp = 'profile';

    $emp_upload_path =   'assests/images/';
    $p = $emp_upload_path;

    echo $p;

    if (!is_dir($p)) {
        mkdir($p,0777);
    }

    $path = $p.$exp.'/';

    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        mkdir($path,0777);
    }

    $model_upload = new upload_mod;
    $file_name    =    "";
    $model_upload->upload_file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model_upload,'userfile');

    if($model_upload->validate()) {
        $model_upload->upload_file->saveAs($path . $model_upload->upload_file);
        $file_name = $model_upload->upload_file;
    }else{
        var_dump($model_upload->getErrors());
    }

    $data['file_name']    = $file_name;
    $q = Employee_mod::model()->imagesave($q , $file_name);    
    $this->redirect(array('employee/list'));
```

MODEL:

```
function data_save($data)
{
    $input = array(
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'middle_name' => $data['middle_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'cnic' => $data['cnic'],
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
        'department' => $data['dept_id'],
        'location' => $data['location'],
        'created_by' => 'admin',
        'team' => $data['id'],
        'des' => $data['des_id'],
        'report_to' => $data['id'],
        'joining_date' => $data['joining_date'],
    );

    $q = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $q->insert('emp',$input);

    $insert_id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
    return $insert_id;
}

function imagesave($empno , $file_name)
{
    $file = array(
        'image' => $file_name
    );

    $q = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $q->update('emp', $file, 'empno=' . $empno);
}

function imageeditsave($empno , $file_name)
{
    $file = array(
        'image' => $file_name
    );

    $q = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $q->update('emp', $file, 'empno=' . $empno);
}

function data_editsave($data,$emp_no)
{
    $input = array(
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'middle_name' => $data['middle_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'cnic' => $data['cnic'],
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
        'department' => $data['dept_id'],
        'location' => $data['location'],
        'created_by' => $data['created_by'],
        'team' => $data['id'],
        'des' => $data['des_id'],
         'report_to' => $data['id'],
        'joining_date' => $data['joining_date'],
    );

    $q = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $q-> update('emp',$input,'empno =' . $emp_no);

    $insert_id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
    return $insert_id;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, You haven't looked at your own code :         $model_upload->upload_file->saveAs( ...);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 $q = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
 $q->update('emp', $file, 'empno=' . $empno);
```

`update` is an ActiveRecord method and you are using it with createCommand! You need to change that code to this:

```
Employee_mod::model()->updateByPk($empno, array('image' => $file_name));
```